# Matrix subtraction endless display issue

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I've been working on a program to display the result of the subtraction of two matrices. The program allows the user to input the size of the matrices, then prompts the user to input values for these two matrices. Lastly, the program is supposed to display these two matrices individually, then display the result of the subtraction of the two.

Currently when the code is ran, the output is just an endless display of numbers. I cannot find what is creating this issue. I would appreciate any input as to what is causing this issue.

Thanks!

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0, j = 0, n=0, a[10][10], b[10][10], c[10][10];
    bool positive = false;

        cout << "Enter the size of the two - dimensional array: ";
        cin >> n;
        while (!positive){
            if (n >= 0){
                positive = true;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Please enter a positive number for the size of the matrix.";
                cin >> n;
            }
        }   
    cout << "Enter the values of the elements of array A" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Enter the values of the elements of array B" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cin >> b[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Matrix A:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; i < n; j++){

            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << "Matrix B:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){

            cout << b[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";   
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << endl;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] - b[i][j];

        }
        cout << "\n";   
    }
    cout << "Matrix A - Matrix B: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << c[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this line is causing the trouble?

```
cout << "Matrix A:" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; i < n; j++){

        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
}
```

Change the for-loop for j (i.e, j < n). See if that helps..

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake :). For the long term benefits, please heed NathanOliver's advice